# Handling Security in a multi tier Windows application

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, security, active-directory

I have an client server solution. The client is wpf and the server is windows service(.net, connected trough wcf).

I Would like my users to have two ways of signing in. One is username and password. Other in to use Windows Security.

The security content should be sent from client to server and the server should validate the user and the role against the active directory. In the username, password scenario, it Would validate using the database.

But what dó i send from client to server? An implementation of IPrincipal? Or just the username, and then the server looks it up? And how do i configure the users on the server with the roles in my applikation? Can i display the active directory dialog and browse users and groups and Then match Them with my own roles?

**Here is what im thinking about doing - update**
Send username/password to server on a wcf line with transport security. Then have the server validate if the supplied username/password is valid AND have access to use the application. Please note that there is both authentication and authorization in this. Not all users (even though they are valid Windows Users) may have access to the application.

e.g. They are 100 employees and bought only 10 licenses.

Comment: If you want to use Windows Auth, I believe you configure IIS to do that, not WCF. (I think by the time the call gets to WCF, the windows authentication check has to already have happened) But I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For the UserName this is the client code

[How to: Authenticate with a User Name and Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

As for the two credentials I think you could do that that two endpoints.

[Multiple Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx)

[WCF Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649763.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Dont know if this is the solution im looking for. I want to enforce roles in my server and only users and roles who have access to my application can login. As far as i know your solution imposes the same security on all uses. The reason for doing this is that i want the customer to buy an amount of users and then enforce that.